# TCL: Need to delete "(double quotes) from strings in tcl skipping first and last. examples are given below

Tags: tcl

I need to replace all double quotes from the below string and keep the first and last double quote. How can I do this?

```
"0 "ifx" "blrcom" "media" "00-00-00-01-01-00" "server" "10.10.10.1" "10.10.10.10" "255.255.255.0" "11.11.11.1" "192.168.1.1" 0 "14.14.14.1"";
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is probably to remove all double quotes (with `string map`) and then put the outer ones back on afterwards (with string concatenation).

```
set str {"0 "ifx" "blrcom" "media" "00-00-00-01-01-00" "server" "10.10.10.1" "10.10.10.10" "255.255.255.0" "11.11.11.1" "192.168.1.1" 0 "14.14.14.1""}
set stripped [string map {\" {}} $str]
set str \"$stripped\"
```

If you've possibly got that semicolon at the end as well, handle it first/last. `string match` and `string trimright` are the right tools.

```
set gotSemi [string match "*;" $str]
set stripped [string map {\" {}} [string trimright $str ";"]]
set str \"$stripped\"
if {$gotSemi} {
    append str ";"
}
```